# Magento 2.3 Add information to cartItem

Tags: magento2.3, cart-items, msi

The shop is working on a magento 2.3 with MSI.

I would like to add two informations to each item in a guest cart endpoint /V1/guest-carts/:cartId.

- The stock from a given source
- A thumbnail from a product custom attribute

What is the best way to achieve this ?

I had try to use extension attribute, but not successfully.

Answer (score 0):

When you work on front-end, the system knows nothing about sources and their number assigned to the given stock/website. 
So, when you work with a shopping cart, you have a scope of Magento website you are working with, by that website you can resolve a Stock assigned to your website (\Magento\InventorySalesApi\Model\StockByWebsiteIdResolverInterface::execute), and from that Stock, you can retrieve product quantity using service - https://github.com/magento-engcom/msi/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/InventorySalesApi/Api/GetProductSalableQtyInterface.php